# Numpy - Matrix multiplication

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

I spent about 2 hours trying to figure out what's going on, but for the life of me I can't figure out why switching the order of matrices when multiplying doesn't seem to work:

Using Python 2.7x:

```
import numpy as np
num_segments = 25
num_vintages = 24
# Create a 3d matrix 25 deep x 24r x 24c
mx_loans_new_loans = np.zeros((num_segments, num_vintages, num_vintages))

# Create the multiplication vector - same as the first dimension of 3d matrix
mult_vector = np.arange(10,35)
len(mult_vector)
```

The intent is to fill in the matrix on the diagonal with the `mult_vector`. 
Here is the part I can't wrap my head around.

This version does not fulfill the intent:

```
for (i, x) in enumerate(mx_loans_new_loans):
    np.fill_diagonal(x, 1)
    x = x * mult_vector[i]
```

The results still spit out just the original matrix with 1's on the diagonal.

This version, however, does work. All I've done is reverse the matrices in the `enumerate`:

```
for (i, x) in enumerate(mult_vector):
    np.fill_diagonal(mx_loans_new_loans[i], 1)
    mx_loans_new_loans[i] = mx_loans_new_loans[i] * x
```

Sidenote:
I've since realized a more optimized version fills the intent:

```
for (i, x) in enumerate(mx_loans_new_loans):
    np.fill_diagonal(x, mult_vector[i])
```

**But does anyone know why the first version doesn't work, but the second version does? What am I missing?** Is this a broadcasting problem or something simpler?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`mx_loans_new_loans` is 3d, (25,24,24).  `x` in the loop is (24,24).  `multi_vector` is (25,); `multivector[i]` a scalar.

The `fill_diagonal` sets the 1s in `x` (in place).  But `x = x * mult_vector[i]`, replaces `x` with a new array, and doesn't change the original.  That is, it reassigns variable `x`.

```
x *= mult_vector[i]
```

should change the diagonals in the original array.

`mx_loans_new_loans[i] = ...` changes this subarray in place.  Again `mx_loans_new_loans[i] *= ...` should work as well.

With `zip` we can iterate on both arrays:

```
In [44]: Z=np.zeros((4,3,3),int)
In [45]: for i,j in zip(Z,np.arange(10,14)):
    ...:     np.fill_diagonal(i,j)
    ...:     
In [46]: Z
Out[46]: 
array([[[10,  0,  0],
        [ 0, 10,  0],
        [ 0,  0, 10]],

       [[11,  0,  0],
        [ 0, 11,  0],
        [ 0,  0, 11]],

       [[12,  0,  0],
        [ 0, 12,  0],
        [ 0,  0, 12]],

       [[13,  0,  0],
        [ 0, 13,  0],
        [ 0,  0, 13]]])
```

We can view all the diagonals as set in the loop with:

```
In [47]: Z[:,np.arange(3),np.arange(3)]
Out[47]: 
array([[10, 10, 10],
       [11, 11, 11],
       [12, 12, 12],
       [13, 13, 13]])
```

And modify them with (not quite right):

```
In [48]: Z[:,np.arange(3),np.arange(3)]=np.arange(20,23)
In [49]: Z
Out[49]: 
array([[[20,  0,  0],
        [ 0, 21,  0],
        [ 0,  0, 22]],

       [[20,  0,  0],
        [ 0, 21,  0],
        [ 0,  0, 22]],

       [[20,  0,  0],
        [ 0, 21,  0],
        [ 0,  0, 22]],

       [[20,  0,  0],
        [ 0, 21,  0],
        [ 0,  0, 22]]])
```

better:

```
In [50]: Z[:,np.arange(3),np.arange(3)]=np.arange(20,24)[:,None]
In [51]: Z
Out[51]: 
array([[[20,  0,  0],
        [ 0, 20,  0],
        [ 0,  0, 20]],

       [[21,  0,  0],
        [ 0, 21,  0],
        [ 0,  0, 21]],

       [[22,  0,  0],
        [ 0, 22,  0],
        [ 0,  0, 22]],

       [[23,  0,  0],
        [ 0, 23,  0],
        [ 0,  0, 23]]])
```

---

Another example of how assignment changes arrays (or not):

```
In [97]: x = np.zeros((2,3),int)
```

`y` is a `view`, a way of looking at one row of `x`:

```
In [99]: y = x[0]
In [100]: id(y)
Out[100]: 2877147400
```

In-place change to `y` appears as a change to `x`:

```
In [101]: y += 3
In [102]: y
Out[102]: array([3, 3, 3])
In [103]: x
Out[103]: 
array([[3, 3, 3],
       [0, 0, 0]])
```

But a `y=` change to `y` breaks the connection.  `y` is no longer a view (row) of `x`, but rather a whole new array.

```
In [104]: y = y + 3
In [105]: y
Out[105]: array([6, 6, 6])
In [106]: x
Out[106]: 
array([[3, 3, 3],
       [0, 0, 0]])
In [107]: id(y)
Out[107]: 2876795264
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer @hpaulj. I'm relatively new to python at this level, and I think that's the part I'm not clear on: as you mentioned, doesn't `np.fill_diagonal(x, 1)` modify `x` in place? So that when moving on to the next line: `x = x * mult_vector[i]`, `x` has already been filled with diagonals. Then `x * mult_vector[i]` is `x` with diagonals filled in `*` the scalar? Thanks again -

Comment: @max370sluggo,  But the `x` on the left of the `=` is not the same as the `x` on the right.  Effectively you wrote `y = x * mult_vector[i]`.  This multiplication is not an in-place operation.

Comment: Thanks @hpaulj - I'm still unclear on what is happening with `x = x * mult_vector[i]`, but you helped solve the issue. Any suggestions on where I can learn more about what's happening (or what topic to research?)

Comment: Actually - I think I'm starting to get it now. `x * mult_vector[i]` creates a new object, and the `x` on the left side now refers to that new object, leaving the original reference (the matrix in the for... loop) unchanged.

Comment: @max370sluggo, I added another example.